# UML BPMN examples

Tags: uml, bpmn

I am looking for a basic business process (a ordering service or something similar) modeled using **UML** and/or **BPMN** for learning purposes. Are there any examples I can get my hand on?

Answer (score 4):

You can find some examples here:

- BPMN examples: https://repository.genmymodel.com/diagrams/bpmn
- UML examples: https://repository.genmymodel.com/diagrams/uml

Select a project and click the green button to clone an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some examples on the main bpmn web site: [www.bpmn.org](http://www.bpmn.org);
you can click on the tab "examples" and you will find some BPMN model examples.

I also suggest downloading BonitaStudio, where you can find some examples and you can run them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try downloading Bonita Open Solution from Bonitasoft's site. The tool comes with a set of Business Processes provided as example like a hiring process. You'll also have the possibility to find some processes on BOS community.

Check here: http://www.bonitasoft.com/products/BPM_downloads

*(Disclaimer: I work at Bonitasoft.)*

Maybe other vendors/tools/community provide some examples.