# What's the best way to document/map similar modules in an application and its dependencies?

Tags: architecture, documentation, software-design, business-process-management

I'm currently searching for sustainable & maintainable ways to document features/modules in our application and to be able to create a sort of mapped database of all the features connected to it. Sure, there will be a lot of manual data entry. We already have JIRA but even with that, it's still not enough.

I'm thinking of sort of like a visual mind map where I could drill down a basic feature and have trees/network of information like similar pages that reuse the same module etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621553/uml-bpmn-examples is helpful for you. I suggest to use [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) for your purposes. As tutorial, I find https://camunda.com/bpmn/ very accessible (and I am not affiliated with them).